# Предлагаю объединить метки “частицы-не-ни” и “не-или-ни”

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено

Предлагаю объединить метки “частицы-не-ни” и “не-или-ни” (сделать метку “не-или-ни” сининимом). Метка  “частицы-не-ни” использована 27 раз, метка “не-или-ни” была употреблена 2 раза, я заменил ее на “частицы-не-ни”.

Дополнение: а может, наоборот:  “не-или-ни” проще и понятней (и не надо спорить, частица это или приставка)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метки объединил, синонимы создал. Основной меткой сделал [не-или-ни](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b8). Спасибо за помощь!